# Ler um arquivo xml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xml

Estou tentando ler um arquivo XML.

```
string pagina = "https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/transactions/notifications/5B93AB-E9FA04FA04D8-24449BAF8A80-E32467?email=diegozanardo@yahoo.com.br&token=DFA3837517594466BCC87D8F397BF15F";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(pagina));
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.Accept = "application/xml";

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());


WebResponse res = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
string returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();
XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();
xm.LoadXml(returnvalue);
XmlNodeList el = xm.GetElementsByTagName("paymentLink");
Response.Redirect(el[0].InnerText);
```

Porém gera o seguinte erro na linha:

```
WebResponse res = request.GetResponse();
```

> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (405)
>   Method Not Allowed.

Comment: Tá com cara que você não está recebendo os dados corretamente. Esta `pagina` está com endereço completo, protocolo, tudo?

Comment: @bigown, adicionei a URL da pagina!

Comment: Eu não tenho experiência com isto, mas será que o fato de ser HTTPS não está gerando problema?

Comment: @bigown, não faço ideia. rsrsrs

Answer (score 1):

A resposta indica que o método que você está usando (`POST`) não é aceito pelo serviço. Tente mudar a linha que define o método do `HttpWebRequest` para usar `GET` que deve funcionar:

```
request.Method = "GET";
```

Mais uma coisa: requisições GET não tem corpo (*request body*), então você pode remover o código que define o `ContentType` e que retorna o *request stream*:

```
string pagina = "https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/transactions/notifications/5B93AB-E9FA04FA04D8-24449BAF8A80-E32467?email=diegozanardo@yahoo.com.br&token=DFA3837517594466BCC87D8F397BF15F";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(pagina));
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "application/xml";

WebResponse res = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
```